# How to add a field to Taxonomy term in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I heard of this feature in Drupal 7. I did a lot of googling but am unable to find an example of how do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browse to admin/structure/taxonomy, then edit the vocabulary that you want to add the field to, like so:
http://screencast.com/t/Idamrat591

That will allow you to field a vocab so you can enter the data for the term under it, hope that helps!